# Rails relationships setup for 5 table db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, has-many-through, relationships

I'm stuck in a circle of indecision and need a shove to break free. I'm a noob with Rails and I'm attempting to translate a pre-existing database using Rails conventions. Basically, I currently have 5 models/tables: Workorders, Mileage_logs, Time_logs, Parts, & Equipment. A Workorder can have many Mileage_logs, Time_logs, and Parts, because each of them is shown on the Workorder's index page. But, that's the seemingly easy part...

I'm getting confused when the Equipment model is introduced because it seems like it's basically the same thing as the Workorder.

What is the best way to handle this relationship setup? Is this an appropriate use for the `has_many :through` convention? Or, is this best done with simply having the `workorder_id` and `equipment_id` in the Mileage_log, Time_log, and Part models and then:

```
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :workorder
    belongs_to :equipment
end

class Mileage_log < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :workorder
    belongs_to :equipment
end

class Time_log < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :workorder
    belongs_to :equipment
end

class Workorder < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :Time_logs
    has_many :Parts
    has_many :Mileage_logs
end

class Equipment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :Time_logs
    has_many :Parts
    has_many :Mileage_logs
end
```

Or, is the `has_many through:` relationship what I should look into for the Workorder & Equipment models?

```
class Workorder < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :parts
    has_many :mileage_logs
    has_many :time_logs
end
class Equipment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :parts, through: :workorder
    has_many :mileage_logs, through: :workorder
    has_many :time_logs, through: :workorder
    has_many :workorders
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Also, any general advice on the route setup would be welcomed as well.